# How to move out from the setOnItemClickListener() function

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using cascaded listviews and i have only one `setOnItemClickListener()` function but on the last listview **I want to moveout from the function `setOnItemClickListener()`**. otherwise my program keeps on waiting for another click event to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is set a different view.